# Open Search 2.9.0 - Failed to Deploy Model

Tags: machine-learning, opensearch, semantic-search

Objective: Try out pretrained model for semantic search using Open Search 2.9.0

Installed OpenSearch 2.9.0 on Mac

Added two properties in yml file:

```
plugins.ml_commons.allow_registering_model_via_url: true
plugins.ml_commons.only_run_on_ml_node: false
```

Started it, have added index data
Then registered a model - works fine

```
{
    "model_id": "DzO9ZIoBhng0Kd-T5nTn",
    "task_type": "REGISTER_MODEL",
    "function_name": "TEXT_EMBEDDING",
    "state": "COMPLETED",
    "worker_node": [
        "5n2HVgg1TBuyxZbOebfOSQ"
    ],
    "create_time": 1693907281577,
    "last_update_time": 1693907356625,
    "is_async": true
}
```

The issue:

Next when trying to deploy the model, getting the issue:

```
{
    "model_id": "DzO9ZIoBhng0Kd-T5nTn",
    "task_type": "DEPLOY_MODEL",
    "function_name": "TEXT_EMBEDDING",
    "state": "FAILED",
    "worker_node": [
        "5n2HVgg1TBuyxZbOebfOSQ"
    ],
    "create_time": 1693907418409,
    "last_update_time": 1693907423996,
    "error": "{\"5n2HVgg1TBuyxZbOebfOSQ\":\"Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native\"}",
    "is_async": true
}
```

And in the console I see:

```
failed to load pytorch native library
```